# Temperature sensor with fans not working in Proteus

Tags: c, temp, pic18, proteus

I would like to know why the simulation is going wrong in the Proteus Professional.
Well, on this circuit and code, I tried to make a Temperature sensor with fans following the following conditions:

[Conditions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTtF8.png)

I'm using a PIC18F4520

This is the code and the error in Proteus:

```
// PIC18F4520 Configuration Bit Settings

// 'C' source line config statements

// CONFIG1H
#pragma config OSC = HS         // Oscillator Selection bits (HS oscillator)
#pragma config FCMEN = OFF      // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable bit (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor disabled)
#pragma config IESO = OFF       // Internal/External Oscillator Switchover bit (Oscillator Switchover mode disabled)

// CONFIG2L
#pragma config PWRT = OFF       // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF      // Brown-out Reset Enable bits (Brown-out Reset disabled in hardware and software)
#pragma config BORV = 3         // Brown Out Reset Voltage bits (Minimum setting)

// CONFIG2H
#pragma config WDT = OFF        // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled (control is placed on the SWDTEN bit))
#pragma config WDTPS = 32768    // Watchdog Timer Postscale Select bits (1:32768)

// CONFIG3H
#pragma config CCP2MX = PORTC   // CCP2 MUX bit (CCP2 input/output is multiplexed with RC1)
#pragma config PBADEN = ON      // PORTB A/D Enable bit (PORTB<4:0> pins are configured as analog input channels on Reset)
#pragma config LPT1OSC = OFF    // Low-Power Timer1 Oscillator Enable bit (Timer1 configured for higher power operation)
#pragma config MCLRE = ON       // MCLR Pin Enable bit (MCLR pin enabled; RE3 input pin disabled)

// CONFIG4L
#pragma config STVREN = ON      // Stack Full/Underflow Reset Enable bit (Stack full/underflow will cause Reset)
#pragma config LVP = OFF        // Single-Supply ICSP Enable bit (Single-Supply ICSP disabled)
#pragma config XINST = OFF      // Extended Instruction Set Enable bit (Instruction set extension and Indexed Addressing mode disabled (Legacy mode))

// CONFIG5L
#pragma config CP0 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) not code-protected)
#pragma config CP1 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) not code-protected)
#pragma config CP2 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) not code-protected)
#pragma config CP3 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) not code-protected)

// CONFIG5H
#pragma config CPB = OFF        // Boot Block Code Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) not code-protected)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data EEPROM Code Protection bit (Data EEPROM not code-protected)

// CONFIG6L
#pragma config WRT0 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT1 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT2 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT3 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) not write-protected)

// CONFIG6H
#pragma config WRTC = OFF       // Configuration Register Write Protection bit (Configuration registers (300000-3000FFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRTB = OFF       // Boot Block Write Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) not write-protected)
#pragma config WRTD = OFF       // Data EEPROM Write Protection bit (Data EEPROM not write-protected)

// CONFIG7L
#pragma config EBTR0 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR1 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR2 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR3 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)

// CONFIG7H
#pragma config EBTRB = OFF      // Boot Block Table Read Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)

// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.

#include <xc.h>
#include"LCD4b_EXSTO.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#define _XTAL_FREQ 8000000

#define FAN1 PORTCbits.RC0
#define FAN2 PORTCbits.RC1
#define RES PORTCbits.RC2
//botao
#define B1 PORTBbits.RB0  

unsigned int VdigADC;
float TENSAO, graus, porcen;

void config_IO()
{
TRISC = 0X00;
PORTC = 0XFF;
}

void config_ADC()
{// PARA O AN0
ADCON0 = 0X01; // Sele??o dos canais anal?gicos; Estado da convers?o e Habilita??o do  Conversor A/D PADRAO
ADCON1 = 0X0E; // Tens?o de refer?ncia; Sele??o de entrada anal?gica | PORTA AN3 -> 1011
ADCON2 = 0X87; // Alinhamento dos Bits (ADRES); Tempo de aquisi??o; Fonte de Clock para o converesor A/D PADRAO
}

void config_FOSC()
{
OSCCON = 0X00;
OSCTUNE = 0X00;
}

void equacao(){
    
    TENSAO = VdigADC * 0.004887585532746823069403714565;
    graus = TENSAO / 0.01190476190476190476190476190476;
    porcen = (graus * 100) / 420;
}

void conv_AN0()
{
    __delay_ms(200);
    ADCON0bits.GO = 1;
    while(ADCON0bits.GO); 
    VdigADC = ADRESH; 
    VdigADC = (VdigADC << 8) + ADRESL;
    equacao();

}
void porc(){
    
    conv_AN0();
    if(porcen<25)
    {
        RES=0;
        FAN1=1;
        FAN2=1;
    }
    else if(porcen>25 && porcen<=50)
    {
        RES=0;
        FAN1=0;
        FAN2=1;
    }
    else if(porcen>50 && porcen<=75)
    {
        RES=0;
        FAN1 =0;
        FAN2=0;
    }
    else if(porcen>75)
    {
        RES=1;
        FAN1 =0;
        FAN2=0;
    }
    
}
void lcd(){//BLOCO DO LCD
    char temperatura[16];
    char percentual[16];
    char fan1[16];
    char fan2[16];
    char res[16];
    
    
    lcd_init();
    lcd_clear();
    __delay_ms(100);
    
    while(B1 == 1){
        lcd_clear();
        porc();
        lcd_write(1,1,"FAN 1:");//linha 1 fan1
        sprintf(fan1, "%d",FAN1);
        lcd_write(1,7,fan1);
        
        lcd_write(1,9,"FAN 2:");//linha 1 fan2
        sprintf(fan2, "%d",FAN2);
        lcd_write(1,16,fan2);
        
        lcd_write(2,1,"RES:");//linha 2 res
        sprintf(res, "%d          ",RES);
        lcd_write(2,6,res);
        __delay_ms(100);
    } 
    lcd_clear();

    __delay_ms(100);
    while(B1==0)// exibe temperatura e porcentagem
    {
        lcd_clear();
        __delay_ms(100);
        porc(); 
        //linha 1
        lcd_write(1,1,"Temp:");
        sprintf(temperatura, "%.1f%cC                     ", graus, 0XDF);
        lcd_write(1,9,temperatura);
        
        //linha 2
        lcd_write(2,1,"Percent:");
        sprintf(percentual, "%.1f%c                       ", porcen, 0X25);
        lcd_write(2,10,percentual);
        __delay_ms(100);
    }
}
void main()
{
    config_FOSC();
    config_ADC();
    config_IO();
    lcd();        
}
```

[Proteus error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ5P9.png)

I tried looking for the error on the internet, but I couldn't find anything that really helped me.

Comment: What are `ADRESH` and `ADRESL`? Why are do you what looks like making a wide address into VdigADC (within `conv_AN0()`) but then multiply that address with a smallish float constant (within `equaca()`)? I think I expect some way of reading the temperature value from an address and then do things with that temperature value. This is of course just guessing. Please explain your understanding of your code. Translating the comments to English and using English identifiers might help. I think you should avoid global variables and instead use function parameters and return values.

Comment: I expected some kind of looping, but once the two loops in `lcd()` are executed the program terminates.

Comment: Please don't post codes and errors as images, post them as text. Have a look at [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page and update your question accordingly.